# Make a half circle with ClipPath

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to build this

[image: snap]

I used a `ClipPath` like this:

```
ClipPath(
  clipper: HeaderClipper(),
  child: Image.asset(
    "assets/images/stores/bg1.jpg",
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
),
```

And this is my `HeaderClipper` class:

```
class HeaderClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();

    final heightFactor = 5 / 8;

    path.lineTo(0, size.height * heightFactor);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      50,
      size.height,
      size.width / 4,
      size.height,
    );

    path.lineTo(size.width * (3 / 4), size.height);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      size.width - 50,
      size.height,
      size.width,
      size.height * heightFactor,
    );

    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);

    path.close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

But I don't know why it doesn't look like the picture. Can you help me what parameters should I change or should I use another method instead of `quadraticBezierTo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply achieve it using - `ClipRRect`

Code:

```
ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(140.0),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(140.0)),
      child: Container(
        child:
            Image(image: NetworkImage('https://placeimg.com/640/480/people')),
      ),
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!